# Authentication failed for user: null

Tags: java, tomcat, stack-trace, vignette

I have an API `"Vignette Collab"` that is running on an Apache stack with Java, I inherited a legacy codebase and need to find where this error is coming from apparently the last developer built a feature that wasn't working and that's where the error is, but no more info. It is using the Drupal webservice module and the code sending the call looks like this

```
 $node = $variables['node'];
 $service = wsclient_service_load('collab_folders');

   if($node->field_oid1):
    $param1 = $node->field_oid1['und'][0]['value'];
    $params1 = array('user'=>'myUser','password'=>'myPass','oid'=>$param1);
    $results1 = $service->getChildren($params1);
    $variables['collabresults1'] = $results1;//
```

Any idea as to where I can begin looking for this error or what it may mean?

The full stack trace is here:::

> ```
> ecmtrtest1: http cmd: lookup, http-bio-81-exec-3, kmapi=true&properties=true&dtd=false&oid=1.59.93   Authentication
> ```
>
> failed for user: null.
>       java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: this method not yet supported on client
>                       at com.intraspect.kmapi.client.KMDocument.getDocType(KMDocument.java:331)
>                       at com.acuitys.ws.impl.CollabServiceImpl.populateProperties(CollabServiceImpl.java:236)
>                       at com.acuitys.ws.impl.CollabServiceImpl.getChildren(CollabServiceImpl.java:83)
>                       at com.acuitys.ws.CollabWebservice.getChildren(CollabWebservice.java:34)
>                       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor758.invoke(Unknown Source)
>                       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>                       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:246)
>                       at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:146)
>                       at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:257)
>                       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:595)
>                       at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:93)
>                       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:554)
>                       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539)
>                       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436)
>                       at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:243)
>                       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
>                       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:444)
>                       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:135)
>                       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:129)
>                       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:160)
>                       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet.doPost(WSSpringServlet.java:52)
>                       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
>                       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>                       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>                       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>                       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>                       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>                       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>                       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>                       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>                       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>                       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>                       at com.intraspect.valves.CollabWebDAVFixValve.invoke(CollabWebDAVFixValve.java:34)
>                       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>                       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
>                       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>                       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
>       [Apr 22, 2016 10:59:51 AM (http-bio-81-exec-3_532)]: Authentication failed for user: null.
>       [Apr 22, 2016 10:59:51 AM (http-bio-81-exec-3_532)]: ecmtrtest1: http cmd: lookup, http-bio-81-exec-3,
>   kmapi=true&properties=true&dtd=false&oid=1.9.2878889
>       [Apr 22, 2016 10:59:51 AM (http-bio-81-exec-3_532)]: Authentication failed for user: null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem appears to be with this line: `$results1 = $service->getChildren($params1);`. The UnsupportedOperationException belongs to the Java Collections framework and means that you are trying to perform some operation on the array $params2 that the java api doesn't support. The first place I would look is at the version of java you are running and the version of java required by the Vignette Collab api. It sounds to me that perhaps a later version of java is required than you are currently using.

You may also want to dig into the api to see what `getChildren()` does, and make sure you are passing in the correct parameter value.